Should we get rid of the beginner tag?
I forget who made the beginner tag when the site opened, but it may have outlived its usefulness.
I use it pretty liberally so people who aren't interested in basic questions can ignore the beginner tag, similar to the rationale given in a meta question I asked a few years ago here.
However, things have changed since the site was created.

From what I can tell, the most useful division seems to be between different proof assistants, with Coq and Lean fighting it out for first place, maybe Isabelle in second place, and a long tail of questions that are prover-agnostic or specific to other provers.
Questions from new contributors don't use the beginner tag, regardless of how much or little experience the user has.
I'm not sure we have any experts who are overwhelmed with non-research-level questions.

So, my opinion is that the beginner tag is solving a non-problem and we should just get rid of it, but in another world perhaps it would have been useful.

I agree. Let's listen to the other mods.

I agree it is not very useful, but on the other hand, it is actively harmful? Should we replace it by a research tag or something similar, to signal explicitly more advanced questions, rather than implicitly (and considering we have better chances that advanced users will use tags more properly than beginners?). In any case, as you say the number of questions is not really overwhelming so tags are not as useful as they are on other SE.

It is not actively harmful, I think it's simply useless.
